# Retaliation Downvotes - Is there way to specifically report or provide justification for this?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

It may not be a big deal for most but just as part of product design for Stack Overflow, is there no way to handle/mitigate retaliation based downvotes?

One scenario that happens often with me is when I comment on a super generic answer which doesn't solve the original question.

The individual who incorrectly answered ends up deleting their answer to save their -ve rep while ends up downvoting your answer just to retaliate.

Comment: You could always downvote without commenting.

Comment: Yes, but that again is a design issue isnt it? If i downvote something I am encouraged to edit the answer or comment to explain what is incorrect with it right? Just downvoting is a way of hiding your identity for sure but it doesnt solve the issue.

Comment: You're certainly not encouraged to edit answers except to correct grammar and that's not really a reason to downvote. You have no obligation to explain what's incorrect with it either.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Snarky comments explaining why they downvoted are not encouraged.

Comment: If it's just a one-off downvote, not really anything you can do about that except try to avoid it in the first place by not commenting.

Comment: @10Rep  let me know if "This doesnt answer OPs question" is snarky enough

Comment: @AkshaySehgal See my answer. I didn't say your comments are snarky, and I'm sorry if I offended you. Many times, people leave rude comments when they downvote, which is the reason it's discouraged.

Comment: Mods can only detect some types of serial downvotes. If it's more serious, only community managers can handle it, and that pathway is swamped at present. If you still want to go that route, I would just use the Contact Us link at the bottom, but you'll need more than just one or two downvotes for them to take your complaint seriously.

Comment: One down-vote is not "retaliation down-votes". You don't know retaliation until you've had MANY down-votes

Comment: The issue is not of serial downvotes, please check this recent situation on this post. Notice the time stamps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226623/how-to-interpret-scikit-learns-pca-when-n-components-are-none/63238234#63238234

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels there is a difference between serial downvotes and retaliation downvotes .. i never said i am facing serial downvotes

Comment: You're right, the issue isn't serial downvotes. The issue is a *non*-issue. And I never said you were either, just that you're making a mountain out of a molehill. Move on.

Comment: Please check the answer below and the comments under it. it seems you havent understood the issue.

Comment: Users are encouraged to downvote answers that they do not think are clear or useful. If they don't think it's an answer to the question, then they *should* downvote it. There's nothing to complain about here. Don't leave any more comments talking about downvotes on the main site; I deleted the ones that were there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for you 'move on' advice, i just came here the right course of action, and i have recieved my answer from the more helpful of the users.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray Ill be more careful about leaving comments next time.

Comment: I see this as a big issue in StackOverflow, some moderator gets upset that his/her answer isn't selected and the question and other better answers are down voted. The entire community suffers.

Comment: What is reason for downvoting this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78018414/how-to-add-adjusted-pvalue-to-the-correlation-analysis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked at your reputation history, and there is only one downvote. How do you know it's them?

You can't know for sure who downvoted your post. I suspect only CM's can see that, but it's irrelevant.

Normally, if a user downvotes multiple posts of your's at the same time, then there is a script that will reverse these votes. It usually takes 24 hours to run. If by that time, nothing reverses, then the downvotes weren't serial(meaning by the same user), or the script didn't detect them for some reason.

However, in your case, the script won't run, since one downvote can't activate anything.

On the topic of downvoting, please keep in mind that:

> You ***don't have to*** provide an explanation for downvoting.

When you downvote, don't comment! That is the main reason why many people retaliate.

Comment: I know its them because they copy pasted my comment on their post with EXACT text (missing an apostrophy) and then deleted their post and pasted it as a comment on my answer with a downvote

Comment: That is reasonable enough an assumption right?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Send me the link, I don't fully understand. If I'm right, they put your comment in their post, and then deleted your post. If they did that, then your answer also gets deleted, doesn't it?

Comment: Sure, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226623/how-to-interpret-scikit-learns-pca-when-n-components-are-none/63238234#63238234. Seems they have just reverted their delete, so you can now see the timestamps as well

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I agree with you, so here's my advice: [Contact StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) and tell them to look into the matter.

Comment: To reiterate what I said above, CMs are indeed the only ones who could rectify this but **it's unlikely they will reverse one downvote**

Comment: @AkshaySehgal - is Ahmet the offending user in this case?

Comment: @JohnRSmith Please don't mention users by name: And the discussion is over.

Comment: Wait up, the OP linked to the actual post in concern here, and everyone reading this can make an assumption about who it was, or, make a wrong assumption.  Ahmet there with the answer may be  completely new person answering the question, and as such, shouldn't be suspected of any nefarious activity.  That's what I am seeking clarity on.   Please don't assume nefariousness on my part.  Although, I am nefarious in certain ways for sure!  ;)

Comment: @JohnRSmith I believe you are correct, that person is the offending user.